# Similarity or Relation between Walsh Hadamard Transform and Slant Transform

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis, transfer-function, matrix

Is there any relation between Walsh Hadamard Transform and Slant Transform? Or is there any common property or similarity?

Comment: Hi! This is a bit broad. What have you been figuring out so far? We don't know what you understand and what you not understand. Since the definitions of these two are pretty different, we can't really tell at which level of understanding we'd need to start explaining things. So, please: Enhance your question by editing it and giving way, way more background! Why you're asking this? What did a comparison of the definitions yield? What is it that you need help with, specifically?

Comment: Any additional feedback  required?

Answer (score 1):

On a 2-sample vector, or $2\times2$ pixel images, Haar, Walsh-Hadamard, or Slant are exactly the same. They are all separable, orthogonal transformations with fast $N\log N$ algorithms. According to [Slant Transform Image Coding](https://scinapse.io/papers/214293012), 1974, it is superior in appearance to the above, only inferior to Karhunen-Loève,  which has no fast enough algorithms.